# Disconnecting Virtual Machine using tscon.exe reduces screen resolution

Tags: windows, automation, virtual-machine, resolution, screen-resolution

I'm running automation tests on vm but as soon as i disconnect from vm using a batch file(tscon.exe) the resolution of vm automatically changes as the resolution is important in my case as i am comparing images

Comment: This is with Windows, correct? If so I have a similar problem and if you tag your question with Windows I can set a bounty on this.